# How can the ICC(1,1) reliability of group A possibly be higher than group B?

Tags: reliability, intraclass-correlation

I have calculated the ICC(1,1) reliability of my groups A and B over 2 trials using SPSS (syntax below), and found (with 95% CI's):

```
ICC(1,1) Group A = .832 [.766, .881]
ICC(1,1) Group B = .801 [.725, .858]

RELIABILITY
  /VARIABLES=trial1 trial2
  /SCALE('ALL VARIABLES') ALL
  /MODEL=ALPHA
  /ICC=MODEL(ONEWAY) CIN=95 TESTVAL=0.
```

I am struggling to understand how the reliability from trial 1 to 2 could possibly be higher for Group A than for Group B of my dataset. It seems counter-intuitive since (1) Group A scores are on average 0.5 higher on trial 2 than trial 1 (a bulk shift that ICC model 1 should pick up since we treat raters, that is, trials, as random - and are checking for absolute agreement not just consistency), while on average Group B scores remain the same, and (2) the degree of change in scores from trial 1 to 2 seems lesser in general (as well as being more central) for Group B than for Group A (see histograms of trial-1-to-2 difference scores below).

After inspecting the data, the idea that the ICC(1,1) reliability as I've calculated it is higher for group A than B makes me wonder if I'm doing it wrong... and if not, where is the hidden variance in group B scores?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I may be closer to finding my own answer... ICC measures the *proportion* of variance attributable to error – hence if the total observed variance increases sufficiently, it is possible for ICC reliability to improve, without a reduction in error variance (or even with a small increase in error variance). This has happened between trial 1 and 2 for my dataset for group A – total variance is pretty large (5.079) compared with that of group B (2.756) at trial 2.

Ideally, to compare like with like, I need to keep the denominator of total variance the same for both groups. I think, since I am expecting zero true changes between trial 1 and 2, I should use the whole-sample between-subjects variance from trial 1. This will require me to calculate ICC from a formula but that is ok.

Comment: The ICC(1,1) (also called consistency ICC) can be interpreted as the % of total variance accounted for by subjects/items variance. Your raters are treated as random effects. If you want to account for variance specific to each group, you may wanrt to use the ICC2 version.